# What would be a good model fit for a rise-and-fall time series data?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, linear-model, nonlinear

I have two time series measurement of protein "activation" under two different conditions, (A) and (B). My end goal is to fit a model and use the model parameter that best describes the rate of "activation".

The data looks similar to panel D below: [(Reference)](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/scisignal.abd2464)

[image: Data similar to panel D]

**Question 1.** Is there a model that best describes the data in panel D?

**Question 2.** Once a model is fit, is it appropriate to hypothesis test/compare the parameter that best describes the rate of "activation" (if this parameter exists?)

**Question 3.** Is it appropriate to split the data to two linear models: a linear model from 0 to max response and from max response to baseline or steady-state. In this case, slope to max response (k1) and slope from max to baseline (k2) would be the parameters to hypothesis test between conditions.

Apologies if I am missing info. But any input is appreciated.

Comment: A random idea: (restricted) distributed lag models (Almon, Koyck, ...) such as [here](https://www.reed.edu/economics/parker/312/tschapters/S13_Ch_3.pdf).